# Workplace sexism against men vs sexism against women

Tags: management, company-culture, company-policy, offices, sexism

(By the way, I am male...)

My male boss was recently seriously berated at work for some sexist comments he had made to a female colleague of mine, which turned into quite a scandal. He was almost fired from his job, and sent on some equality training course.

Now, as part of the investigation, I was called in and interviewed by a team from human resources. I was asked to confirm or deny whether I had heard him say any of the things which he was accused of saying. There were three things, and if I remember correctly, they were: calling her "darling", telling her that she had "beautiful hair", and saying that all of the male employees "probably want to date her". The only complaints were about things he had said -- there was nothing about physical contact etc.

I told them that I hadn't heard him say any of these things, and then they moved onto asking me about sexism generally at my work. They asked me if I was aware of anything at all involving people other than this boss and this female colleague. It then dawned on me that my other boss, who is female (I kind of have two bosses), often says similar things to *me*. She certainly regularly calls me "darling" too, and she often comments on how she thinks I am good looking, and that I must be very popular with female employees. At a work party, she even once told me that if she wasn't married, then she would "fancy me".

I had never thought twice about these comments made to me, but seeing as I was being asked, I told all this during the interview. I then told them that I saw it as pretty much the same level of comments as have been directed to my female colleague. In return, they said that this was fine, because I hadn't previously made a complaint about it. I thought this was odd, given that these rules should probably apply regardless of whether a complaint is made.

Anyway, I then asked them what would happen, if I did make a complaint about these comments to me (just out of curiosity, I didn't actually want to make this complaint). They then told me that because it was a woman saying these things to a man, then it was "less harmful", whereas from a man these comments "come across as sleazier". They then explained that for a woman saying things to a man, the comments would have to be significantly more provocative and sexual for it to be taken seriously as a complaint, when these comments would be taken seriously if it was a man saying it to a woman. They said that comments like this from a man are usually interpreted as "oppressive and objectifying", whereas from a woman they are usually interpreted as "friendly and complementary".

This really shocked me, because it is such an obvious double standard. Everything else was equal about this -- the types of comments made to each other, and the ages of everyone (both bosses ~40, both me and my colleague ~30) -- and the only different was the gender. So my company effectively have a policy that makes it a much worse offence for a man to be sexist than for a woman to be sexist.

- Is there a way to raise the awareness of female colleagues that sexism works in both ways? Should one be calm and objective or more emotional when arguing about it?
- How to overcome the problem that it may be perceived as not so serious if female superiors make compliments to male colleagues? Just approach them directly? How does HR react, given that HR is sometimes dominantly female?
- How to react if a female colleague state that "women are better at ..." (usually claiming better social skills)?

Comment: `what should I do about it` Join an MRA forum (kidding). That depends on your end-goal, which is missing from your question. Do you want to update your company policy for gender blindness? Or perhaps have the female boss get the same treatment?

Comment: @John Great question! I'm left wondering if this isn't fixable, but I can't really judge your company culture from the question. (other than that they're really careful not to get sued) What do you think would happen if you would voice your concern about the double standard with the HR person or with the HR department?

Comment: "*They then told me that because it was a woman saying these things to a man, then it was "less harmful"*' Oooh boy. Are you by chance part of a large organization and do the people you spoke with from HR have anyone managing *them*? **This is the kind of thing HR people lose their jobs over,** assuming your company cares, which they might not. That said, I'm not actually seeing an answerable question here. Can I assume that your question is "if this *is* odd, how can I make it clear that I'm very uncomfortable with HR displaying this kind of bias?".

Comment: The statements by your bosses qualify as sexual harassment but I don't think those are in any way sexist. That statement by HR however? That's not just double standards that is some top-notch sexism right there.

Comment: Am I the only one for whom this reads like obvious agenda-driven baiting? HR's response is such an oblivious and self-destructive liability as to be implausible.

Comment: I think this is probably the common response.  The problem is that HR was only there to investigate one employee's bad behavior, having to investigate two employees at the same time means a lot more work along with internal political and external legal danger.  The average human response is to sweep the second accusation under the rug, at least until the first accusation blows over or never bring it up again.  Not that I agree at all with that, its just that humans are weak at accepting unexpected burdens.

Comment: Often times people who complain about something legally dangerous get dismissed like was [alleged at Wells-fargo in their recent scandel](http://money.cnn.com/2016/09/21/investing/wells-fargo-fired-workers-retaliation-fake-accounts/).

Comment: As an aside, applying a single standard to two different situations and getting two different results is not a double standard... although it may look like one if you only look at the results and not the common rationale. This may or may not be relevant to the case at hand.

Comment: Your first decision is *how much do you care?*  If it's important to you, then you should take this kind of thing straight to the top.  If not, just drop it.  The way the world is (at least in the US) right now, the kind of comments that would get a person fired going from M->F are commonplace and considered 'harmless' when going from F->M.

Comment: @benxyzzy You seem to be a tad ignorant on the current narrative of gender relations in the workplace, particularly in North America. This situation is more common than sexual harassment being treated equally. Anyway, for OP, you cannot win in these situations. Not at this stage of the narrative. Hopefully things will get better, but for now, they run the show in the workplace, and you're safest walking on eggshells right now.

Answer (score 38):

Why do anything?

I don't see any reason for you to jeapordise working relationships, stir the pot and make trouble over relatively innocuous remarks.

It's best not to get involved in anything but your actual work unless there is a serious issue affecting you personally which interferes with your primary objective of making money and rising in your career. Especially when it is a manager you would be complaining about.

Double standards are everywhere from politics to small group dynamics, they're a fact of social interaction that people deal with all the time. They're even enshrined in law.

A general rule of thumb is not to get involved with anyone else's disciplinary measures unless it's your role, you have a professional stake in its outcome, or you have the leverage to force the issue without repercussions to yourself.

Comment: +1 - I'm a great believer in picking your battles wisely, and there's no benefit whatsoever to be gained from picking this one.

Comment: Why do anything? Because it's creating a hostile environment. No one ever had any hostile intentions, but one group has some more degree of freedom in their communication. I would certainly not want to work in conditions like these. @berry120 The benefit is that you are not the next one at the gallow for trying to be nice and polite. I find complimenting outfit, or looks, carrying the same meaning as legendary americam dinner invitations, they don't carry any, except maybe a complimentary. If the rules are unreasonable, they should be at least equally unreasonable for everyone.

Comment: @luk32 Yeah, life is often unfair, but this is minor compared to a lot of things, can whinge about every little thing or get ahead, life's too short. If you want to be a bit of an activist and take the high ground then there's plenty of much bigger worthier causes.

Comment: @luk32 Is it creating a hostile environment if it didn't occur to the OP that these conditions could be hostile until someone pointed it out to him? You can't base a complaint of harassment/hostile workplace on "I was fine with what I was happening until someone else was investigated and I decided there was an unfair double standard so I filed my own complaint." If words or actions are taken in the future that make the OP uncomfortable, that's a different story. But this is about past behaviour that had no impact on the OP's work environment. If it had, he wouldn't have forgotten it happened.

Comment: "Why do anything? Because it's creating a hostile environment." The hostile environment is created by persecuting men; also persecuting women does not make the environment for men less hostile. As a man, I'd like for hostility in general being reduced, not being equalized by also treating women like potential threats.

Comment: @pmf so would I, unfortunately I live in a 'real' World firmly grounded in reality rather than a Disney fairy tale.

Comment: Your male boss is about to have his ass handed to him for the exact same thing your female boss is allowed to get away with, and the best voted answer is ‘dont rock the boat’ and the question gets closed?! This is infuriating. (I don’t mean it personally towards Kilisi, but in general towards out society.)

Comment: @nl-x reality can be pretty frustrating and unfair

Answer (score 23):

**Feelings matter.** The exact same words delivered between two different people can evoke different feelings. If the person hearing it is vulnerable and has been harassed before, the words can bring up fear and worry, reminding them of a previous experience that started similarly. Since there's no business need for comments like these, they are best avoided. If the person hearing it is privileged and doesn't believe they would ever be harassed, the words don't bring up those kinds of feelings and the person hearing them knows they can safely be ignored.

This isn't a double standard. It is the HR people caring about **the impact of the words on the hearer** more than the actual words. You have said to us and to them that you didn't care, weren't hurt, had forgotten, and so on. I wouldn't expect anyone to pursue action in that case. Your colleague did care, was hurt, and went to the HR people for help. I hope her boss learns how not to hurt her, or others, in the future.

In the meantime please avoid strutting around saying "I don't get it. My boss says all that to me and it doesn't bother me at all, and nobody tells her not to." That will only upset your colleague, your boss, and your colleagues boss as well.

Comment: Agreed, but as a general rule I suspect it's actually HR caring about the potential impact of the company's reputation if word got out that they allowed sexist comments, more than them caring about the wellbeing of the individual!

Comment: `If the person hearing them [...] started similarly` Totally true. Unfortunately that wasn't HR's position, who did not consider who was hurt and who wasn't, but rather who was male and female.

Comment: how can you say they didn't consider who was hurt? Someone complained. Someone else didn't complain and told HR they didn't consider the comments hurtful or problematic. HR specifically mentioned that the OP didn't complain. And yes, the context - who the comments were directed to - was also mentioned. I think their explanation to the OP was somewhat clumsy, and assumed a lot of background that OP clearly doesn't have, but that's not the question here.

Comment: Well, I would like to hope this was the case, but OP asked about the situation specifically. HR, being honest, did not explaing it like you, that the difference is the emotions of the side feeling hurt and the personal context, but on their gender. I think they just explained business standard, but it is a double standard, the same actions are being judged differently. And in the example case based on gender context. Personally I am not sure if personal context should be taken into account either, unless the harrased worker gave impressions they didn't like the form of communication.

Comment: But since there's no reasonable way to tell who is and is not vulnerable, the only logical solution would be to ban it on both sides, right? If it's allowed only in one direction, that sounds like the default assumption is "all women are vulnerable and all men are not", which sounds exactly like a double standard.

Comment: @Erik the only logical behavior for a person considering calling their direct report "darling" or the like is not to do it. Absolutely correct. You can't know how such things will feel to the hearer and there's no good reason to say them. When things have been said, HR can consider the actual impact of the actual words. The part where they carried on to generalize about men and women was clumsy at best, possibly worse.

Comment: But even when they are said, HR can't really consider the actual impact of the words, that's impossible. There's no objective measure of how much words hurt someone, not to mention that the impact of those words is also a function of the affected person's relationship with the alleged harasser.
All HR can do is make a strict, consistent policy with whatever solution and stick to it. And alternating between solutions based on the complainant's gender is definitely a double standard.

Comment: You're out of my area of expertise. But **the person who heard the words** in both cases is **sitting right there in the room** telling HR the impact. They can relate how they were hurt, worried, or changed their behavior afterwards. Or how they were not. Your claim that rules must like this or that is not reality. All these things involve a degree of judgement which is why not just anyone hears these cases and rules on them.

Comment: Yes, and I would be fine if that is the complainant testimony was the standard for measuring impact, but it's not. Because if it was, the stance would be that for a guy, it would also depend on how that particular guy is effected by those words, not what the general opinion of men is. HR would have asked how much he was hurt by his boss's actions rather than telling him it's complimentary. He might not (and it sounds like he would not) file a complaint but HR's double standard shows that even if he was hurt enough to complain, he would not be taken seriously.

Comment: Very disingenuous answer as it struggles to suggest that a man complaining about sexual harassment would be treated the same as a woman complaining about sexual harassment (in most cases). I am certain the answerer knows this is objectively false.

Comment: it does no such thing. The OP asked "why is it different when the same words were used" and I said "because the impact of those words was different." It makes no attempt (struggles? thanks!) to predict anything about what would happen about a complaint from a man who was actually hurt by such words. Don't complain I do a poor job of something I do not do at all, try to do, intend to do, etc.

Comment: @KateGregory: Yes, the OP said that he didn't take what his female boss said as hurtful. But he asked "what if I was hurt by the same words in the same way" and HR told him basically that a woman could say these things, no matter how hurtful they were taken.

Answer (score 9):

#### A male boss saying "darling" to a female employee

The statements made by your male boss is a typical first step of a courtship ritual for a man. Any woman who has been the target of unwanted attention a couple of times will recognize it. It may look perfectly civilized on the surface, and it probably feels this way to the boss too. It is still a signal that the boss would very much like to create more intimacy. Even if he does not plan to act on that desire, it is still extremely uncomfortable for the targeted woman. It legitimately creeps her out.

A very devious thing here is that men tend to overestimate the reciprocity of attraction. If he sends a mild signal of attraction and the woman does not immediately act with aversion but simply takes it with embarrassed silence, he sees this as acceptance enough to press a bit more if the situation presents itself. If the woman is too shy to openly rebuff him for whatever reason, this creates a very awkward situation. And the fewest people are brave enough to openly confront their boss, especially when it comes to personal matters.

#### Woman -> man sexual harassment

Now you are asking, what about the reverse situation? Well, if we have a woman boss signalling her sexual attraction to a male employee, then you are correct. This is as much of a sexism issue as the other way around. Maybe men are wired in a way that they are less likely to perceive attention from a woman as unwanted, but it still can happen. And when it happens, they are entitled to be taken seriously, and to receive support in dealing with it.

#### A female boss calling a male employee "darling"

Statements like "you have nice hair" or calling someone "darling" are not connected to sexual attraction for women the way they are for men. Women frequently use them with people to whom they are not attracted, and rarely make them part of their courtship ritual. While they are statements whose [relationship aspect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-sides_model) dominates their factual information aspect, they do not establish an admirer/pursued relationship when used by women. Conversely, you will not hear a straight man calling their male employee "darling", because that would imply such a relationship. Human language is complex like that.

It is difficult to define what statements made by a woman would be equivalent to those made by your male boss. This is because women tend to use more nonverbal behavior at the early steps of the courtship ritual. If you were to notice that your female boss is wearing lipstick only on days when she has a meeting scheduled with you, this would be a comparable signal to a man's "you have nice hair".

#### Is this an example of double standard?

I am not denying that a double standard exists, with men having it hard to convince people that they can be the target of sexism. But the situation you describe is not an example of the double standard. It is a sensible policy which does take into account the intricacies of human communication. The words uttered may be the same, but the real signal behind them is quite different.

---

#### The fine print - please read if you disagree with the above

To preempt critics, because it's a rather sensitive topic: please do not try to draw too broad generalizations from this post. I am perfectly aware that there are courtship behaviors which men and women have in common. A woman patting a man's bum is just as inappropriate as a man patting a woman's bum. The post focuses on the exact kind of statement noted in the question.

Also, I am aware that there are individual differences. There can be women who send early verbal signals of attraction, or men who manage to use "darling" without being sleazy. Still, the answer above covers the average situation pretty well. The policy exists to establish the standard operation procedure for the average situation, but in the individual case, it matters whether the target is creeped out or not.

I am also sure that I will get comments saying that the differences I described above shouldn't exist, are not natural, describe a patriarchal norm, etc. A debate over nature vs. nurture would be irrelevant here. Fact is, we are living in a world in which the difference exists. Targets of sexual harassment should be given support based on the reality they live in and not on "if women behaved exactly as men and reacted to external stimuli exactly as men, the world would be simpler and we'd have real equality".

Another topic I didn't touch on is that same-gender harassment also exists, that transgender harassment is different from harassment between cisgendered people, etc. I kept the answer heteronormative, because it is complex enough without me addressing issues with which I have little experience and which are not relevant for the concrete situation experienced by the OP.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with your answer. It does show, however, that sometimes when you aim for equality you still need to recognize and acknowledge the differences that exist between genders.

Comment: 'If you were to notice that your female boss is wearing lipstick only on days when she has a meeting scheduled with you, this would be a comparable signal to a man's "you have nice hair"'... and what would happen if I went to HR with that information?

Comment: @SaadFarooq probably not the same as when a woman goes with the information "my male boss is always commenting on my appearance". There are differences here. First, what is bad about harassment is *unwanted* attention. If the target realizes that the other person is attracted to them but does not feel creeped out and does not have the dilemma of "do I bear out an unpleasant situation or do I jeopardize my job and reputation by protesting", then nothing needs to be done. And statistically, a man noticing a woman's attention is less likely to be creeped out than the other way round. (cont.)

Comment: (cont). Second, HR departments have caught up on the man->woman harassment but the other way round is still not widely recognized and addressed, partly because of the first point (it is rarer, so people conveniently forget that it can happen). Third, proving nonverbal courtship behavior in a legally convincing way is much harder than proving verbal behavior ("your honor, she shakes her hips when she passes me"). So HR acts on the man's flirts but not the woman's flirts. Which is, again, a description of the status quo, without commenting on whether this is how it *should* be.

Comment: I agree... my point was that it's not comparable, is it?

Comment: The point here is that it explains that "why doesn't HR punish a woman who flirts with a male subordinate" and "why doesn't HR punish a woman who tells her male subordinate that he has nice hair" are two different questions, because for women, "you have nice hair" =/= flirting. Is it comparable? It depends on what you want to compare. For the point I was making, I compared the action of a woman flirting with the action of a man flirting, not the consequences of those actions.

Comment: But what about the part where she says he "must be very popular with female employees" and that "if she wasn't married, then she would fancy him". Surely that is significantly more explicit than "darling".

Comment: The situation described is absolutely a double standard. What about the other comments? Saying that OP must be popular with female employees, and even going as far to say that boss would fancy him if she wasn't married. You can't convince me that there's nothing wrong with that. It's this kind of thinking that makes it so much harder for men to report things or complain when things actually do happen that affect them. Sexual harassment against men is less common than it is against women, yes, but *it's not nearly as rare as people think it is.*

Comment: If a man says "I would have dated you [under other circumstances]", the woman can react in a rejecting, neutral or accepting way. If she is openly rejecting, she's likely to get ridiculed for being a bitch and making a mountain out of molehill. If she is either neutral (says nothing, or even does something slightly negative like turning away) or accepting, she can be 90+ % certain that in the future, that man will invite her out, or give her a pat on the back, or something even more personal. If she does not want it, she is in a lose-lose situation, especially if she is too timid to (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) defend herself when the next advance comes. She instead starts dreading meeting the man, feels awkward and intimidated in his presence, etc. This is what makes is "harassment" and not an arbitrary decision by society to count that statement as inappropriate. If the situation is reversed, and the man says nothing, there is 90+ % certainty that nothing of this kind will follow. So men don't learn to react with dread to such statements. Not because women don't make advances on men, but because there is little correlation between "I would have dated you if not X" and making advances.

Comment: So yes, if a man does feel discomfort, he should confront the woman and ask her to stop. If he feels more than discomfort, he should report it and is entitled to being taken seriously. Even if he misinterpreted the woman's intent. But women tend to separate "you are attractive" and "I am attracted to you" more than men do, they need more reasons than attraction to pursue a mate, and so this kind of signal is not as much of a signal as it would have been if said by a man. Whenever I heard a woman say "I would have dated you but for X", then she seriously would not date the person.

Comment: Downvoted for making a wide range of very odd, completely biased statements and generalizations about men and women's behaviour for which there is no evidence. If you're going to make such large generalizations about men and women I would suggest providing some research pointing to your conclusions.

Comment: I disagree with your answer and explanation. This is clearly a case of a double-standard in workplace sexual harassment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an obvious double standard because you are not in the same position to begin with, being male. You just wrote you hadn't actually thought about it before, that's a luxury women don't have in general. That's just a fact. That's why it makes perfect sense to consider that the exact same words don't have the same meaning when uttered by a woman. That context makes all the difference.

From that perspective, what you *should* do about the whole situation is educated yourself about the issues and focus on the more pressing problem (it's not men's rights or your boss relatively minor inconvenience…).

Comment: `It's not an obvious double standard because you are not in the same position to begin with, being {black / jewish / foreign}` You're saying it's OK to treat people differently because they're born a certain way. Rules apply to people, not genders (or races etc.). Therefore it's a double-standard.

Comment: @rath That's not really the point, the point is that language has meaning in context. It's obviously stupid to pretend that both uses of the word “darling“ have the same implications or consequences, ergo the difference lies in the act itself, not in the people (or gender, etc.) committing it. Also, it's just silly to consider that caring about sexism means I would condone racism. There is a larger debate about the best way to address it but it's not what's at stake here.

Comment: And it's always funny to see people suddenly care deeply about equality and gender-blindness and act as if being forced to attend a training was a major human rights' violation, while a very real case of harassment does not seem to bother them too much. That, to me, is infinitely more important than theoretical points about double standards.

Comment: `the difference lies in the act itself, not in the people (or gender, etc.) committing it` It seems we're in agreement! (re next comment:) I don't think this is a major case of harassment. Don't get me wrong, it could be, but it doesn't sound like it from the OP's descriptions.

Comment: @Relaxed *It's obviously stupid to pretend that both uses of the word “darling“ have the same implications or consequences* and you being present when this word was uttered know which context was it? Or are you imply that **independently of the context** if a male call a female darling then *it must be* sexual harassment, while a female calling a male darling *cannot be it*? If your answer is "it depends on the context, and if you are male the context is this one" then **you** are sexist. Sure you have to take into account the context, but genders themselves are *not* enough context to judge.

Comment: @rath Your blanket statement about rules exclusively applying to people is ridiculous. Totally fair rules can apply to sexes (I reject the concept of gender), so long as the rule is about a significant and arguably objective difference between the sexes. For example, a policy might say new mothers may take an extra break of 20 minutes twice a day to use the nursing mothers' room to pump or nurse. Since that rule is rooted in an objective difference between sexes, it's completely legitimate. So it really is the standard one has for what constitutes an objective difference, NOT a global thing..

Comment: @Bakuriu Who utters the word and about whom are key aspect of the context so I am not sure what you are asking. Sure, other elements might be relevant but that's kind of my point: You can't simply assume there is a double standard at play because one use of the word is deemed problematic and another less so (which was the OP's main question). How you can read my answer as implying anything is “independent of the context” is beyond me.

Comment: @Relaxed You must be kidding!?!  Your answer / response is a sexist double-standard addressing a sexist double standard question from the OP.  Wow!!

Comment: @tale852150 I am not kidding. But I am not surprised some people would resist understanding the issue. What I am saying is not very different from Kate's answer, incidentally.

Comment: I think neither you nor Kate are seeing the 'whole' picture and are looking at it through a (female) sexist 'lense' -- in this case sexist against men.  It is still 'sexist' and your explanation is 'sexist'.  Maybe the OP (and you and Kate) 'hadn't actually thought about it' because it doesn't get enough attention.  Your lack of sensitivity surprises (and concerns) me.  Apparently you believe 'sexism' is only a domain for women.  It is not. Please reread the top comment/response to your answer again from user rath.  That user is correct is her/his statement.